# docker-compose / postgres - how to disable data persistence?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using `postgres` image form [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).
This image persist db data on host.

I want to disable this and get clear instance
each time when I run docker-compose file.

How to do this?

Comment: `docker-compose down`  should do that for you, As `docker-compose stop` will only hibernate containers ,`down` will completely destroy containers (but not images).
and the next time you run it should be clear ?

Comment: I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `docker-compose down` instant of `docker-compose stop`.

`docker-compose stop` will only hibernate containers,

While `down` will completely destroy containers (but not images).

So, the next time you ran `docker-compose up` after the `down` command should have a clear database instance.

Comment: **Be aware:** if you use `ubuntu 22.04LTS` and have `docker-compose` from ubuntu repo this will not work.Ubuntu is providing very old version of `docker-compose` where this switch not work correctly.